# Wrong mime type when loading script from github.com

Tags: javascript, http, browser, mime-types, mime

I am trying to load this script directly from Github:

https://github.com/sumanjs/sce-plugin-template/blob/master/dist/plugin.js

here is my code:

```
const url = this.pluginUrl;  // https://github.com/sumanjs/sce-plugin-template/blob/master/dist/plugin.js

const script = document.createElement('script');

script.onload = function () {
  alert('loaded script successfully');
};

script.onerror = function (e) {
  console.error(e);
  alert('error loading script:' + JSON.stringify(e));
};

script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;

document.head.appendChild(script);
```

but I get the following error:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://github.com/sumanjs/sce-plugin-template/blob/master/dist/plugin.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME
>   type checking is enabled.

Is there anything I can do to make the script executable?

Comment: use the "raw" link `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sumanjs/sce-plugin-template/master/dist/plugin.js`

Comment: Yeah I think it's: https://rawgit.com/sumanjs/sce-plugin-template/master/dist/plugin.js

Comment: raw.githubusercontent.com became rawgit.com

Comment: what? I clicked on the raw link ... and got the url I offered ... if you get something else, then good for you :p

Comment: maybe the old is a mirror idk

Comment: By now rawgit.com is dead, any solution in 2024?